# How to show all unique types of a pattern?

Tags: search

I have a very large file containing about, for example, 5 million lines like this:

```
Songs=****, Singers=****
Singers=***
Songs=***
.... # many many lines
SongType=***
... # many many lines again
Album=***, Singers=**
```

Since all characters replaced by `*` are Chinese characters I use `/[a-zA-Z]*=` to match "Songs", "Singers". And I don't know if I've matched the third: "SongType" since I cannot see it using my eyes, let alone the fourth: "Album".

The problem is that: can I use a vague pattern, in my case `[a-zA-Z]*=` to know all distinct possibilities(of the same pattern)? I mean all the four strings here.

Of course I can use `g` command to delete all that matched and see those left. But what if the fifth and others are so rare that I cannot pick them out in the left lines? And in this way the "Album" is deleted and I can never find it.

I have tried to first copy all matched strings to a register and then `sort u` it in an other file to check, but failed because of the register limitation.

Comment: `The problem is that the file is too large and contains may not only these three type and I want to check all the matched distinctions.` I'm not really sure I understand the question. Do you want to search for different strings in the same pattern as nobe4 showed you or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Are you asking how to know what exactly your pattern is matching in the file?

Comment: Ok I think I understand: You want to get in one place all the strings matching the pattern `[a-zA-Z]*=` right? I think your idea of putting it all in a register was good what was your limitation?

Comment: Yes, and they should be distinct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
:let b:types=[]
:%s/[A-Za-z]*\>/\=add(b:types, submatch(0))/ng
:echo uniq(b:types)
```

This searches for the pattern `/[A-Za-z]*\>` and adds the result to the List variable `b:types`. Since we are only interested in the adding the matches to the list, and don't want to change the buffer, we use the `n` flag to the `:s` command. The `g` flag is there, to get all matches.

Now this will populate your list with all matches, so since we are only interested in the uniq entries, we run the `uniq()` function on the result again.

Note, the `uniq()` function is only available with a Vim 7.4.500 or so, so it is relative recent.

If you are further interested in the statistics, you can do it like this:

```
function! Count(match)
  if has_key(b:types, a:match)
      let b:types[a:match]+=1
  else
      let b:types[a:match]=1
  endif
  return a:match
endfu
let b:types={}
%s/[A-Za-z]*\>/\=Count(submatch(0))/gn
echo b:types
```

This will count each match. The output of the `b:types` variable might look like this:

```
{'SongType': 1, 'Songs': 2, 'Singers': 3, 'Album': 1}
```

Comment: I've tried but it's not that effective as expected.

Comment: What you mean with `not that effective as expected`?

Comment: I want to know if there is a command to get the unique matches in a particular register? Thanks.

Comment: Well, your question did not mention that you want to use specifically registers for that, but you can of course use a register instead of a variable in the first solution I mentioned.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can print the b:types to a file?

Comment: Love this solution. I'm just having to use `uniq(sort(b:types))`...