# Yank only matched unique strings of a pattern in lines to a register?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I have a file containing lines in the following form:

```
this is line 1 and
this is line 2 and
this is line 4 and
this is line 8 and 
23, and this 56 should not be yanked
this is line 9 and this is line 2 and this is line 1 
all numbers not followed 'line' should not copied like this one 23
and this is line 8 but it's duplicated so as the 2 and 1 above. 
line 3
and so on ....
```

I want to find all numbers, unique the better, `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `9`, `3` and store them in a register.

I have tried:

1. `:g/\vline (\d)/y B`, which yanks all the whole lines which contain the pattern
2. `:%s/\vline (\d)/\setreg('B', submatch(1))/n`, which result in nothing except I change `1` to `0` (and what is in the register is the same as the previous one)

I am wondering if I can yank only what I want in lines and store them into the register?

Since this question is at least not duplicated, I want to edit it to get an answer. The requirements become 2:
1. improvement to the second solution in this question, except or include the typo.
2. add the unique feature. That's the matched strings in the register should be unique. I have raised a [related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8906/1788) on this point but I have not found an elegant solution. I mean a command is better than a multi-line script.

Thanks very much.

Comment: typo I think... should be `/\=setreg`

Comment: @spasic yeah, you're right. It works after taking your suggestion.

Comment: And I should first reset the register `b` by `qbq`.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: not sure, you can request mod help I suppose via the flag option

Comment: You should also set register `b` to linewise: `qbq`, then `:%s/line \zs\d\+\ze/\=setreg('B', submatch(0), 'V')/gn`

Comment: @spasic You should post that as an answer so that this questions shows up as answered.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, I would prefer someone else to write a complete answer.. other than typo, I am not very familiar with what is happening.. for ex, whether Sato's comment is an improvement or not

Comment: @DJMcMayhem So am I. Yeah, an answer, an improvement the better, is required.

Comment: @SatoKatsura add the g to match all strings in a line is good, but would you please explain a bit your comment by writing an complete answer? Some other improvements are highly appreciated.