# How to execute with call and <C-R>/ matching?

Tags: regular-expression, search, normal-mode, functions

I want to count the searching pattern and here is my code:

```
execute '%s/' <C-R>/ '/\=' . Count(submatch(0)) . '/gn'
```

Here is my Count function:

```
function! Count(match)
  if has_key(b:types, a:match)
      let b:types[a:match]+=1
  else
      let b:types[a:match]=1
  endif
  return a:match
endfu
```

I borrowed the function from this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8914/1788) by Christian Brabandt.

I have tried the following option to combine the searching part `<C-R>/` and the function calling part `Count(submatch(0))` and the rest but all cannot work:

```
execute '%s/' . <C-R>/ . '/\=' . Count(submatch(0)) . '/gn'
```

And I have read the help document by entering `:help execute` and [this tutorial](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html).

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you need `<c-r>/`, doesn't that do what you want: `%s//\=Count(submatch(0))/gn`

Comment: I want to match the strings I was previously searching for.

Comment: @LernerZhang thats what an empty pattern does

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up a few concepts...

You can use `<C-R>` from Insert or Command-line mode (when typing an Ex command after entering it with a `:`) to insert the *literal* contents of a register. (See [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R).)

So you can use that in a direct mapping (without the indirection of `:execute`), like so:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :%s/<C-R>//\=Count(submatch(0))/gn<CR>
```

When this mapping gets executed (with `<Leader>c`, which defaults to `\c` if you haven't set `mapleader`), the `<C-R>/` sequence will expand to the contents of the search register and will be inserted as part of the Ex command.

If, instead, you want to use `:execute` (because you're not in the context of a mapping, for instance you're inside a function), then what you need is to assemble a *string* with the full command you want to execute.

In that case, you want to use `@/`, which returns the contents of the search register as a string, that you can use as part of an expression. (See [`:help expression-syntax`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expression-syntax), which has an entry for `@r` that evaluates to "contents of register `r`.")

Another issue with your attempt is that you had `Count()` as a function call, but you actually want it to be part of the string, since it's only supposed to be evaluated by the `\=` in the replacement of the `:substitute` command.

Putting it all together:

```
execute '%s/'.@/.'/\=Count(submatch(0))/gn'
```

Finally, as pointed out in [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/how-to-execute-with-call-and-c-r-matching#comment39858_22034) from [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt), in this particular case you don't need to expand the search register at all, since if you use a `:substitute` command without a pattern (empty pattern), the last searched pattern will be used instead. So you don't actually need `<C-R>/`, `@/` or `execute` at all, all you need is:

```
%s//\=Count(submatch(0))/gn
```

In a function, this command will work directly (it's a valid Ex command.) In a mapping, all you need is to prepend `:` and add a `<CR>` at the end. Pretty straightforward!